# Game programming implement chunks

Tags: dictionary, random, libgdx, infinite, chunks

i'm working on a simple game project with libgdx and i need some help to make a random infinite world. After googling for hours i knew that many games use the "chunk theory" to generate an infinite map and also implement tiles. There are many things i don't understand... for example:

What is a tile? and a chunk?
How can i implement this "chunk theory" in a game?
Is this the best way to generate an infinite random map?

can someone answer my questions to make some clarifications in my mind?
Thanks in advance

Comment: making a random infinate world is not simple. Unless it's flat and without other features. Generating chunks is the way to go. You don't have infinate memory, so you cannot generate an infinate map. It's that simple.

Comment: I don't know the details, but I do know that it has to do with creating a chunk of the map only when it's needed. As a player gets too close to the edge of what is already generated another chunk would be generated in that direction. This way your world can go infinitely far without an infinitely large file.

Comment: under "infinite map" do you mean having one map and if the player gets to the end they should start from the beginning of the same map? i.e repeating map which never ends? Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Tile-based maps are maps, which are organized as a grid. A `Tile` is then a cell of this grid and objects are placed inside this `Tile`/cell and can't be placed between to cells. Think about Minecraft, every Block there is one Tile.
A chunk is a part of the map, containing many `Tile`s. It has a fixed size and is used to be able to load only part of an infinite map.
Imagine a map with a size of 1600*1600 `Tile`s. You won't be able to see all `Tile`s at once. Also you don't need to update the logic for the whole map, as it won't affect you anyway. So you split your map into little parts, so called chunks, which have a fixed size (for example 16*16).
Depending on your position, adjacent chunks are loaded and far chunks are unloaded. So if you move from south to nord, chunks in the nord are loaded, chunks in the south are unloaded.
I never implemented a chunk-system myself, so i can't tell you how to implement it, but i guess there are many tutorials out there.
This is not the way to generate infinite maps, but the way to store, load and work with huge maps. The generation is usualy done with some noise functions, but thats a different story.
Anyways i suggest you to start with something smaller and simpler. Rushing into to complex things will just discourage you.